# Python print on same line after delay

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def get(url):
    print 'GET: ' + url,
    r = requests.get(url)
    print 'DONE'
    return r

get('https://www.###.com/getfoo')
```

The output:

> GET: https://www.###.com/getfoo DONE

`request.get` needs about 5 seconds to get a result. *However* the output displays after those 5 sec, not the first imedeately and the **DONE** after 5 seconds.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bcs print() doen not flush to stdout;

You can do it like this

```
import requests

from sys import stdout

def get(url):
    stdout.write( 'GET: ' + url+"\n");
    stdout.flush(); # this func() will flush all to stdout
    r = requests.get(url);
    print("DONE");
    return r;

get("http://programmersforum.ru/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the console is line-buffering the output. Call `sys.stdout.flush()` in order to flush it.